# Using Elastic4s to register a query with the percolator

Tags: scala, elastic4s, elasticsearch-percolate

I'm trying to register a percolator query with the elastic4s library. After much research I've found I need to use something like:

```
val myQuery = """ { "query" : { "match" : { "foo" : "bar" } } } """

esClient.execute( register id 12345 into "baz" query myQuery )
```

As if I'm doing this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/baz/.percolator/12345' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "foo" : "bar"
        }
    }
}'
```

But whenever I try running esClient.execute I end up getting a few parsing errors, but it works fine through the curl:

```
[info]   org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorException: failed to parse query [987654]
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parsePercolatorDocument(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:182)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry$RealTimePercolatorOperationListener.preIndex(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:301)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.indexing.ShardIndexingService.preIndex(ShardIndexingService.java:146)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:565)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine$Index.execute(Engine.java:836)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:1073)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:170)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.performOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:579)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase$1.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:452)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: Failed to parse query [{"query":{"match":{"foo":"bar"}}}]
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:243)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:257)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parseInnerQuery(IndexQueryParserService.java:244)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parseQuery(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:208)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parsePercolatorDocument(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:179)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry$RealTimePercolatorOperationListener.preIndex(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:301)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.indexing.ShardIndexingService.preIndex(ShardIndexingService.java:146)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:565)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine$Index.execute(Engine.java:836)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportReplicationAction.java:1073)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Cannot parse '{"query":{"match":{"foo":"bar"}}}': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 30.
[info] Was expecting one of:
[info]     "TO" ...
[info]     <RANGE_QUOTED> ...
[info]     <RANGE_GOOP> ...
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:123)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MapperQueryParser.parse(MapperQueryParser.java:848)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:227)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:257)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parseInnerQuery(IndexQueryParserService.java:244)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parseQuery(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:208)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry.parsePercolatorDocument(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:179)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.percolator.PercolatorQueriesRegistry$RealTimePercolatorOperationListener.preIndex(PercolatorQueriesRegistry.java:301)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.indexing.ShardIndexingService.preIndex(ShardIndexingService.java:146)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:565)
[info]   ...
[info]   Cause: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 30.
[info] Was expecting one of:
[info]     "TO" ...
[info]     <RANGE_QUOTED> ...
[info]     <RANGE_GOOP> ...
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.generateParseException(QueryParser.java:698)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.jj_consume_token(QueryParser.java:580)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:394)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:247)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:171)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:160)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase.parse(QueryParserBase.java:118)
[info]   at org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MapperQueryParser.parse(MapperQueryParser.java:848)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryStringQueryParser.parse(QueryStringQueryParser.java:227)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:257)
[info]   ...
```

So I've got the feeling that I need to format the query differently, but it's not in the docs and I can't seem to find any examples out there. I've tried a few other formats like so:

```
val myQuery2 = """ "query" : { "match" : { "foo" : "bar" } } """
val myQuery3 = """ { "match" : { "foo" : "bar" } } """
val myQuery4 = """ "match" : { "foo" : "bar" } """
```

But nothing seems to be able to work, the only thing I've gotten to work was just having it like:

```
val myQuery5 = "query"
```

But with this I cannot specify what I actually want to match on. Anyone have any experience with this, or any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` method accepts a string, but the string is a [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and not a json fragment as you have tried. If the query string format is not suitable, then you need to create the query using the elastic4s query dsl, eg

```
termQuery("field", "value")
```

or

```
matchQuery("field", "value")
```

etc. There are many query types, and they can be nested with a bool query.